# How to reload the previous view controller on back button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have two view controller **A** & **B**.On `ViewController` **A** i am displaying data from server.I have nav button Update to go to `ViewController` **B**.On **B** i can update the data which was shown on `ViewController` **B**.Now when data is updated on server i show an alert **'Update Success'** on click of Ok i go to previous `ViewController`.But i don't see the updated data because i removed the `ViewController` **B** from stack but **A** is not reloded.

**Code for going back to ViewController A**

```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: use viewWillappear method

Comment: where to use view will appear?@iAnurag

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you are sending a web call from `viewDidLoad()`. So in order to update your **viewController A** Add your web call method in `viewWillAppear()`

Answer (score 3):

The state of your "data" on view controller A has not changed and you need to refresh it. If you're fetching data for view controller A within `-viewDidLoad`, try moving it to a different life cycle method like `-viewWillAppear`.

Remember, `-viewDidLoad` gets called only when the view controller loads which happens once, however `-viewWillAppear` gets called before it appears which will happen often if you're hopping back and forth between views.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call your API method in `viewWillAppear()`. So, whenever you come back from any viewController, your updated server data will reload itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer@Ranu